# How to assign multiple variables in one call?

Tags: c++

I have a text file that contains a list of random fractional math problems.  I'm able to output a random problem for the user to solve; however, I'm having difficulty making my function output the problems numbers.  For example, the random, string problem generated is " -1/4 + 1/20 ", the purpose of the function, findFractions, is to get -1, 4, 1, 20 and assign them to variables so that I may calculate the problem's answer and later use my gcd function.  In this case, I'm only able to output the number -1. I can make 4 separate functions, but is it possible to use one function.  I cannot use pointers yet by the way.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int const MAX_PROBLEMS = 50;
char findOperator(string problem);
char findfractions(string problem);

int main()
{
    int op, int frac;
    string oneProblem, problems[MAX_PROBLEMS], question;
    int mode, count = 0;

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    ifstream mathProblems;
    mathProblems.open("P4Problems.txt");
        if (!mathProblems)
        {
            cout << "Error : No file found. " << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    getline(mathProblems, oneProblem);
        while(!mathProblems.eof())
        {
            problems[count] = oneProblem;
            count ++;
            getline(mathProblems, oneProblem);
        }
    int randIndex = rand() % count;
        cout << problems[randIndex] << endl; // Displays a random problem
        question = problems[randIndex];
        op = findOperator(question); // Retrieves problem's symbol i.e. *
        frac = findFractions(question); //Retrieves only one number


char findOperator(string problem)
{
    char op, slash;
    int n1, d1, n2, d2;
    istringstream iss;

    iss.str(problem);
    iss >> n1 >> slash >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> slash >> d2;
    return op;
}
char findFraction(string problem)
{
    char op, slash;
    int n1, d1, n2, d2;
    istringstream iss;

    iss.str(problem);
    iss >> n1 >> slash >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> slash >> d2;
    return n1, d1, n2, d2;
}
```

Comment: You cannot return multiple values like this: `return n1, d1, n2, d2;` it will evaluate the last value (`d2`) only (lookup the comma operator). Use reference parameters to provide output to more than one valuee from a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reference parameters to obtain more than one result from a function:

```
void findFraction(string problem, int &n1, int&d1, int& n2, int& d2)
{
    char op, slash;
    istringstream iss(problem);
    iss >> n1 >> slash >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> slash >> d2;
}
```

Comment: @JamesHenrick Sure, de nada.